# How to split an area/polygon by a border/line

Tags: r, ggplot2

So, I have a sumatra.shp file, and also a bukit_barisan.shp file. And I want to separate sumatra.shp which are bounded by the center line of Bukit Barisan.
`[image: sumatra]

```
# Convert SpatialPolygonsDataFrame to a data frame
sumatra_df <- fortify(sumatera)
bukit_df <-fortify(bukit_barisan)
# Membuat interpolasi spline untuk garis tengah
spline_fit <- smooth.spline(bukit_df$long, bukit_df$lat)
# Membuat data frame untuk garis tengah
centerline <- data.frame(long = spline_fit$x, lat = spline_fit$y)
# Load necessary libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(rnaturalearthdata)
library(sf)
world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")
class(world)
id <- world%>%filter(admin == "Indonesia")
library("ggspatial")
ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = id,fill = "white") + 
  geom_sf(data = world[world$admin != "Indonesia", ], fill = "antiquewhite") + 
  geom_polygon(data = western_df, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), fill = "lightgray", color = "lightgray") +
  geom_point(data = centerline, aes(x = long, y = lat), color = "black", size = 0.01) + 
  annotate(geom = "text", x = 101.5, y = 0.25, label = "Sumatra", fontface = "italic", color = "grey22", size = 6, angle = -45) + 
  annotation_scale(location = "bl", width_hint = 0.5) + 
  annotation_north_arrow(location = "bl", which_north = "true", pad_x = unit(0.75, "in"), pad_y = unit(0.5, "in"), style = north_arrow_fancy_orienteering) + 
  coord_sf(xlim = c(94, 107), ylim = c(-8, 6), expand = FALSE) + 
  xlab("Longitude") + ylab("Latitude") + 
  ggtitle("") + 
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(color = gray(0.5), linetype = "dashed", size = 0.2), 
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "aliceblue"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lwgeom::st_split()` and `sf::st_collection_extract()` to split an area/polygon by another geometry.

Below is an example using a generic polygon and a line that cuts across the polygon.

```r
library(sf)
library(lwgeom)

# Create example shapes
area <-
  st_as_sfc("POINT(0 0)") |>
  st_buffer(dist = 1)

area <-
  st_as_sfc("LINESTRING(-.2 .2, 0 0, 0.1 0.1)") |>
  st_buffer(dist = 1)

border <-
  st_as_sfc("LINESTRING(-1 1, -0.93 0.96, -0.9 0.92, -0.86 0.88, -0.71 0.82, -0.63 0.68, -0.54 0.6, -0.48 0.55, -0.31 0.49, -0.27 0.28, -0.19 0.2, -0.18 0.17, -0.04 -0.01, 0 0, 0.04 0.01, 0.18 -0.17, 0.19 -0.2, 0.27 -0.28, 0.31 -0.49, 0.48 -0.55, 0.54 -0.6, 0.63 -0.68, 0.71 -0.82, 0.86 -0.88, 0.9 -0.92, 0.93 -0.96, 1 -1)")

plot(area)
plot(border, add = TRUE)
```

[image]

```r
# Split area and extract polygons
area_split <-
  st_split(area, border) |>
  st_collection_extract("POLYGON")

plot(area_split, col = c("blue", "green"))
```

[image]

## Example with Shapefiles

Below is an example of how to do it with the shape files you provided. You can change the `smoothness` of the center line. You might also have to adjust the coordinates of the extra point added to the centerline (see the explanation below).

```r
library(rnaturalearth)
library(lwgeom)
library(sf)
library(ggspatial)
library(tidyverse)
world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")

# read shape file folders for sumatra and bukit_barisan
sumatra <- st_read("sumatra")
bukit_barisan <- st_read("bukit_barisan")

# Turn off spherical model to avoid invalid loop issues with sumatra shape
sf_use_s2(FALSE)

# Prepare context shapes
south_east_asia <-
  world |>
  filter(subregion == "South-Eastern Asia")

# function to create centerline
make_centerline <- function(polygon, smoothness = .6) {
  pol_coords <- st_coordinates(polygon)
  out <-
    smooth.spline(pol_coords[, "X"], pol_coords[, "Y"], spar = smoothness)
  data.frame(long = out$x, lat = out$y)
}

centerline <-
  make_centerline(bukit_barisan, .6) |>
  # centerline is to short/ needs to go accross the shape
  # adding on point to make it long enough
  add_row(lat = -5.5, long = 105.3)

centerline_sf <-
  st_as_sf(centerline,
           coords = c("long", "lat"),
           crs = st_crs(sumatra)) |>
  st_combine() |>
  st_cast("LINESTRING")

# Sumatra is the 2nd largest polygon. We use that information to extract
# the shape of Sumatra island.
sumatra_island <-
  sumatra |>
  summarise() |>
  st_cast("POLYGON") |>
  mutate(area = st_area(geometry)) |>
  arrange(desc(area)) |>
  slice(2)
#> although coordinates are longitude/latitude, st_union assumes that they are
#> planar

# Split Island by centerline and name areas
sumatra_island_split <-
  sumatra_island |>
  st_split(centerline_sf) |>
  st_collection_extract(type = "POLYGON") |>
  mutate(bukit_split = c("NE", "SW"))

# Plot
sumatra_island_split |>
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = south_east_asia, aes(fill = geounit == "Indonesia")) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = bukit_split)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(
    "FALSE" = "antiquewhite",
    "TRUE" = "white",
    NE = "grey70",
    SW = "grey80"
  )) +
  guides(fill = "none") +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(94, 107),
           ylim = c(-8, 6),
           expand = FALSE) +
  annotate(
    geom = "text",
    x = 101.5,
    y = 0.25,
    label = "Sumatra",
    fontface = "italic",
    color = "grey22",
    size = 6,
    angle = -45
  ) +
  annotation_scale(location = "bl", width_hint = 0.5) +
  annotation_north_arrow(
    location = "bl",
    which_north = "true",
    pad_x = unit(0.75, "in"),
    pad_y = unit(0.5, "in"),
    style = north_arrow_fancy_orienteering
  ) +
  xlab("Longitude") + ylab("Latitude") +
  theme(
    panel.grid.major = element_line(
      color = gray(0.5),
      linetype = "dashed",
      size = 0.2
    ),
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "aliceblue")
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Oke thanks, here is the link to my shp data for bukit_barisan and for all indonesia region, please filter it by (xlim = c(94, 107), ylim = c(-8, 6)). Thank you very much. I also add an example picture for split sumatra which are bounded by barisan mountains.
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1XzV_cF3n-Lq0DAFN_tuhwxzy4DgT0Rr0?usp=share_link

Comment: I added an example do my answer that uses the shapefiles you provided.